# Keep text input scrolling synchronized

Tags: javascript, dom

This one's a challenge:

Suppose you have two text inputs, as in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TrevorBurnham/GhMmX/). When the user "scrolls" inside of one (e.g. by moving the cursor to the far right or left), I'd like to "scroll" the other so that it stays in sync.  Can this be done, at least in modern browsers?

Comment: I believe it is not possible.

Comment: Can I assume both will be fixed-width fonts?

Comment: @rami I'm inclined to believe you. I thought I'd be able to do it with `setSelectionRange`, but that only induces scrolling on the input if it has focus, and both inputs can't have focus simultaneously. Still, even a hacky solution would be cool.

Comment: @HeitorChang I'd be interested in seeing a fixed-width font solution, but I don't see that as the major hurdle.

Comment: @TrevorBurnham You could try to build a 'fake input field' - but I guess it would be awful.

Comment: You could adapt an existing, decent looking 'fake input' in an IFrame. Or to resolve the focus problem, focus on the text that needs to be moved then focus again.

Comment: I have a hack that works for pressing the right arrow key on the top input box up to Z (but not twice). Nothing else works. This hack approach isn't sustainable :( http://jsfiddle.net/GhMmX/5/

Answer (score 0):

I would change the text that isn't being input to an IFrame. If both need to be inputs, then dynamically switch your element from iframe to input when it is focused on/away from.

In the input box, you can find where the caret is by using the selection properties; then the IFrame can then be scrolled using scrollTo.

I'm afraid I don't have a complete solution for finding out exactly the scroll state of the input box.